# How can I make my CSS grid even with the background color?

Tags: html, css, grid, padding

I have been trying to make an even 3x2 grid. Some of the blocks are longer and the others and I want them all to be the same length. What would be the best CSS practice to accomplish that? The pictures is what I've accomplished so far.

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="service-block-two single-item" id="service_pest">
<div class="inner-box">
<div class="content">
<div class="clearfix top-area">
<div class="text">
<h4>Insect Control</h4>
</div>
</div>
<p>Insect control is an on going maintenance issue on Nantucket. We recommend foundation treatments 2-3 times per year to keep all kinds of insects at bay. Ants, pill bugs, earwigs and a whole host of other insects can be a nuisance, let us deal with them so you don't have too.
</p><br>
<div class="link"><a href="http://mjstokes.com/buzzoff/pest-control/" class="btn-style-one">More Details</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.service-block-two{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7f7;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;

}

.service-block-two .content p {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

.service-block-two .content .link {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. You'll get more help and better answers.

Comment: Thanks but I believe I've provided enough code to get the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `grid` is a great option and works well, where supported.

If browser support is a concern, you can also use `flexbox` which has slightly better support. Regardless of which, you'll need vendor prefixes.

Code Pen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeQREE

[image: Codepen screenshot]

CSS changes are fairly straight forward. Parent/wrapping elements would need the following:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

The simplest change for the children would be a width. Something like:

```
width: 31%;
margin: 1%;
```

(Total width would be 33% or 3 across)

Hope this helps!

- Grid support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid
- Flex support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this very easily with the new [css grid](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-css-grid-in-5-minutes-f582e87b1228) feature. browser support is quite good. you might need to add vendor prefixes to have maximum browser support.

Basically, you need a parent div which holds/wraps its children (for your case that would be the grey boxes).

suppose this is the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and the css to make this a 3(column)x2(row) grid would be:

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-gap: 15px;
}

.child {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

All columns in a row will be of same height and equal to the tallest column. Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/khairul_anik/pen/KEXopL) link to see it in action.